# Check a string if a letter is used only once Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

How do i check that each letter is used only once in the string inputed by the user and return boolean if true

Comment: What did you try, and what is not working?

Comment: Not sure how to go about it yet

Comment: validateCipher :: Char -> String -> Bool

Answer (score 2):

For

```
appearsOnlyOnce :: String -> Bool
```

an inefficient (quadratic) way to do so is by

```
appearsOnlyOnce [] = True
appearsOnlyOnce (x:xs)
    | x `elem` xs = False
    | otherwise = appearsOnlyOnce xs
```

A more efficient, but more complicated way, would be to sort and check adjacent elements.

Comment: Thanks, Willem Van Onsem!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way that's not too inefficient:

```
import Data.Containers.ListUtils

noDuplicates :: Ord a => [a] -> Bool
noDuplicates xs = xs == nubOrd xs
```

`nubOrd` removes duplicates, keeping the other elements in order. If there's a duplicate, then the nubbed list will differ from the original.